# Force Linebreak in Pageblock Table

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple visualforce page that I am exporting to excel.  There is a nested loop and I need to be able to force a line break (new excel row) after each iteration of the inner loop.  How would I go about that?

My page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Pay_Period__c" extensions="PayPeriodExport_extn" sidebar="false" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" cache="true">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Export Results">    
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Timesheets}" var="TS"> 
            <apex:repeat value="{!TS.Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__r}" var="BTSD"> 
                <apex:column value="{!TS.Employee__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!BTSD.Program_Name_Short__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!mapTotalHrs[TS.ID][BTSD.Budgeted_Program__c]}"/> <!--- Need line break here --> 
            </apex:repeat>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use breakBefore:

```
<apex:column breakBefore="true" value="{!TS.Employee__c}"/>
```

Or, you could probably use an apex:panelGrid:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Timesheets}" var="TS"> 
      <apex:panelGrid columns="3">
        <apex:repeat value="{!TS.Budgeted_Timesheet_Distributions__r}" var="BTSD"> 
            <apex:outputField value="{!TS.Employee__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!BTSD.Program_Name_Short__c}"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!mapTotalHrs[TS.ID][BTSD.Budgeted_Program__c]}"/>
        </apex:repeat>
      </apex:panelGrid>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
```